# Using token access for Google SpreadSheet API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-api

The question is simple.
I got the access_token by Oauth 2. and I want to access spreadsheet on google to read.
But When I read api from https://developers.google.com/sheets/ .
I don't get where to put access_token or do i even need it.

I tried to put my access-token on url and failed..
for instance:  var sample_url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0Ago31FFWG3xZrdHF2bWNjcTJFLXJ6UUHYT3dEakdEaXc&hl=en&output=html?accesstoken=" + accesstoken;
I got the response back. it says "{"data":{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}},"status":403,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1ZduILENRVcnzXTynV00j9puWJEvGgz-EcxOgoPRpOGI/values/A1:D3?ya29.Ci87A42OTqtIqXylTU7QxZALwJjRuf_oXf2FJ-MTY7QvXgWzPhZEKhi4Yhn7HVVV7g","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}" 
I know I have to attach the access-token somehow, but i don't know how.
Do you guy have any idea for the spreadsheet api?

Thank you for reading this

Comment: In what way did it "fail"? Did you get a specific error message?

Comment: I tried to access to google spreadsheet by the following code.             https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1ZduILENRVcnzXTynV00j9puWJEvGgz-EcxOgoPRpOGI/values/         As a result, I got    {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1ZduILENRVcnzXTynV00j9puWJEvGgz-EcxOgoPRpOGI/values/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: the problem is I don't know what the error massage does meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the ionic-framework, but to use the access token, you should either add that into the HTTP headers (e.g. `Authorization: Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`) or include that in your query string,

Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#callinganapi

---

There is a mistake in your `sample_url`, it should be `&access_token=` instead of `?accesstoken=`

It should be,

```
var sample_url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub"
               + "?key=0Ago31FFWG3xZrdHF2bWNjcTJFLXJ6UUHYT3dEakdEaXc"
               + "&hl=en&output=html&access_token=" + accesstoken;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for replying. Actually  I noticed that and changed access_token and tried I got an error code 403, message 'The request cannot be identified with a client project'. I think I have to put the key as what you did. Is it google API Key? How Can I get API Key from OAuth 2.0?  It only give me access_token

Answer (score 0):

I had a same requirement of accessing the google spreadsheet from the ionic cellphone, and we have used tabletop.js. Using this we were able to read the spreadsheet completely.
Try this if it helps you anyway.
https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop

Comment: Thanks you, If my part is not feasible anytime soon, I will try to use tabletop.js